# Название таблицы из SQL

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как можно получить название таблицы из `SELECT` запроса?

Пробую так

```
preg_match("/FROM `(.*?)_(.*?)`/i", '', $maches);
```

И ничего.

Comment: А может у вас в имени таблицы подчеркивания нет или имя не заключено в обратные апострофы. Или у вас не mysql и имена таблиц заключаются не в обратные апострофы. Или пробелов после `from` более одного или там вообще перевод каретки. так что не помешало бы тестируемую строку привести и проверить ее на regex101.com например

Comment: Или может вы во втором параметре preg_match написали так же как тут и вообще строку не передали ему на разбор :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот другой вариант:

```
/FROM\s+`?((?<!`)(?:\w{1,64})(?!`)|(?<=`)[^`\.\/\n]{1,64}(?=`))`?(?:\s|$)/i
```

И с апострофами, и без апострофов результат возвращает в первом элементе.

Тест https://regex101.com/r/oT7dX8/2

Comment: Я правда совершенно не понимаю зачем так сложно, `FROM\s+'?(\w+)'?` (апострофы обратные конечно, не знаю как их тут написать) отлично дает тот же результат, я не смог придумать когда бы он не работал. И так же как и любой другой вариант глючит, если в списке select встретится имя поля заканчивающееся на `from`

Comment: Ладно, уговорили, придумал, ваш вариант понимает спец-символы если в апострофах имя. Правда имя схемы указанное перед именем таблицы не берет

Answer (score 1):

можно начать с такого

```
/FROM\s+((\w+)\s+|`([^`]+)`\s?)/i
```

[тут попробовать и немного объяснений](https://www.regex101.com/r/sQ0gC8/1)

Comment: Все работает но с запросом SELECT * FROM `ddd_categories` не работает не на regex101 не в php

Comment: Достаточно делать пробельные элементы в конце патерна опциональными. Поправил